# Mysql Update all rows in column with multi conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with name is Posts like below:

```
ID    ID_parent     type     ID_parent_old    ID_old
11         0        topic          0            1
22         0        topic          0            2
33         0        topic          0            3
44         0        reply          1            0
55         0        reply          2            0
...        ...      ...           ...          ...
```

after update I'll have something like:

```
ID    ID_parent     type     ID_parent_old    ID_old
11         0        topic          0            1
22         0        topic          0            2
33         0        topic          0            3
44         11       reply          1            0
55         22       reply          2            0
...        ...      ...           ...          ...
```

So, how to do that? Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to make it clearer? I am not sure of your problem...

Comment: can you please explain more ??

Comment: @fancyPants Thanks for your time, I'm not a programmer. I asking this question because I need your helps. The question has updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you well this is what you need :

```
UPDATE Posts p1, Posts p2 
SET p1.ID_parent = p2.ID 
WHERE p1.type = 'reply' 
AND p2.type='topic'
AND p1.ID_parent_old = p2.ID_old
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you're understand what i need but it not working for me. Any solutions?

Comment: @BeenYoung I updated my answer based on your updated post. Check this query now.